# chrome can extensions track browsing activity and other data even when disabled?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I searched this on google and on superuser but found no answer. I want to know if the installed extensions on chrome can access or track browsing activity or/and other data (that it says to get access to when being installed) even when they are disabled.

Comment: If they are disabled any tracking they might or might not do would be disabled.  If you suspect the extensions are tracking your usage use the non-tracking mode which enforces that behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound Where does one find the "non-tracking mode"? I cannot find anything related on Google (except for the *Do not track* option, but this does not enforce any behavior).

Comment: [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en)

Comment: And if an extension is *re-enabled* (or new ones enabled), could it look at stored information from the past? What risks are there with re-enabling an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled extensions aren't loaded and can't interact with your browser.

Once an extension is disabled, you might want to restart Chrome because the extension code can still be loaded in open tabs.